# Check if a minecraft server has whitelist enabled

Tags: java, networking, minecraft

I know that it's possible to get some information about a remote minecraft server such as:

- Current players / max players
- MOTD
- Version

But it is possible to get the status of the whitelist on any server?

```
  Socket socket = new Socket();
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), 1 * 1000);

  DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

  out.write(0xFE);

  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

  int b;
  while ((b = in .read()) != -1) {
   if (b != 0 && b > 16 && b != 255 && b != 23 && b != 24) {
    str.append((char) b);
   }
  }

  String[] data = str.toString().split("§");
  String motd = data[0];
  int onlinePlayers = Integer.valueOf(data[1]);
  int maxPlayers = Integer.valueOf(data[2]);
```

I know that it would be possible by joining the server and checking if the user was kicked for "You are not white-listed on this server". But this would take way too long.

So is there actually a way to check if the server has whitelist enabled by not joining the server?

Comment: Given that that information is not sent over from the server to the client in the server info packet, no.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hard code the servers to get the whitelisted players. Just use the Bukkit API that includes whitelist methods.

To get the whitelist players from file:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getWhitelistedPlayers();
```

To check whatever the whitelist is enabled:

```
Bukkit.getServer().hasWhitelist();
```